# Sonicwall TZ105 Site to Site VPN Created can ping gateways but can't ping network from other site

Tags: routing, firewall, ping, sonicwall

Need help here

Site B

```
TZ105 
x0 Lan 192.168.162.1
X1 WAN 64.x.x.x
X2 LAN 10.0.3.1
```

Site A

```
TZ300
X0 LAN 10.0.1.1
X1 WAN 69.x.x.x
```

VPN tunnel set up as VPN SITE TO SITE and is Green

From Site A I can ping `10.0.3.1`
From Site B I can ping `10.0.1.1` and everything else on this network

From Site A, I can only ping `10.0.3.1`. Although I cannot access a single service, VMConsole, or anything else on the 10.0.3.0 network. I understand that firewall needs to be able to allow for ping on 10.0.3.0 network.

Any ideas?

SITE B
Secondly, I'm going to be connecting up a VOIP/SIP network onto this router for Site B. Do I need to create a VLAN for the Phones? Do I need to create a VLAN for the 10.0.3.0 network?

Comment: This was configured from a factory restore because we didn't have the username or password.

Comment: Just a few quick thoughts...Have you tried to run a traceroute and see where packets are dropped? In the Access Rule in the B allowing the entire A LAN or only the distant router IP? Is the A LAN in the WAN zone of router B? If you cannot initiate any traffic, then it's not ICMP being blocked in the firewall.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to check out these settings and I'll report back with results. I was not able to tracert past the private IP of 10.0.3.1 or 192.168.192.1 gateway of either router. I can ping the

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure you put the remote network into both sides go to VPN->Configure-> Newtwork  and make sure you have the correct networks selected and that they have the whole network range not just the gateway address object. For what I expect you are doing I would setup the local networks to Firewalled Subnets on both, and note what you have for the REMOTE network name. Then go to Firewall-> Address Objects-> Select Custom radio button. This will show you your remote networks and look for the remote network name, and make sure its a Range not a host and that it has the correct range.

You technically don't have to create a VLAN. Depending on the number of phones and how important quality is you can get by with just plugging the phones in. I have a small office (4 Phones and 5 pcs) that I have all on the same subnet no fancy VLAN and no issues. I only use VLAN if I only have one network cable run to each desk. IE passing through the phones to the computers. If I have the cable already ran(or the time to do so myself) A central PoE switch will save you lots of headache in the future.

Comment: Thank you I'm going to try these out. I'll report back with my results.